# jQuery hover on stacked elements (with 'tipsy')

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, hover, tooltip

I am currently using the [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) plugin for jquery to display lightweight tooltips. Works great, for non-nested elements.

Lets say I have:

```
<span>
    abc
    <span>def</span>
    ghi
</span>
```

and I have a hoverevent on each span tag, I get weird result when I try to hover over the inner span tag. I only want it to display the actually hovered element. Nothing else.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gion_13s solution for a while. But it turns out to be very demanding on the browser/cpu on larger sets of data. I came up with a better solution, based on his code:

```
    $('body').on('mousemove', '.backref_hover', function(e){
    // prevent the event from bubbling up
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // force a hide on other targeted elements (such as the span parent)
    $(this).parent().children('.backref_hover').not(this).trigger('mouseleave');

    // force a show on this element (such as thespan parent)
    $(this).tipsy('show');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Tipsy was designed as a simple plugin that works out of the box. Although there are some configurable settings, they may not cover all the use-cases.
But, it does provide an api (`$(el).tipsy(methodName)`) which makes it some-what extendable.
By using it's api, you can force a behaviour (like a `show/hide`) based on your own rules.

Here's how I would write this workaround :

```
$('span')
    // init tipsy
    .tipsy({
        title : function(){
            return $(this).data('tipsy-title');
        }        
    })
   // overwrite the triggering logic
   .on('mousemove', function(e){
       // prevent the event from bubbling up
       e.stopPropagation();

       // force a hide on other targeted elements (suchas the span parent)
       $('span').not(this).tipsy('hide');

       // force a show on this element (such as thespan parent)
       $(this).tipsy('show');
    });​
```

You can see the above code in action by [clicking on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/XgbkQ/).

**Update**
I've updated the code in order to suite your html markup :

```
var $tips = $('.backref_hover')
       .tipsy()
       .on('mousemove', function(e){
           // prevent the event from bubbling up
           e.stopPropagation();

           // force a hide on other targeted elements (such as the span parent)
           $tips.not(this).trigger('mouseleave');

           // force a show on this element (such as thespan parent)
           $(this).tipsy('show');
        });​
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/XgbkQ/4/) is the online demo.

**Update #2**
Here's a demo that works on dynamic added spans :

```
$('.backref_hover').tipsy({live:true});

$('body').on('mousemove', '.backref_hover', function(e){
   // prevent the event from bubbling up
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();

   // force a hide on other targeted elements (such as the span parent)
   $('.backref_hover').not(this).trigger('mouseleave');

   // force a show on this element (such as thespan parent)
   $(this).tipsy('show');
});
```

@Lindrian : All I was saying in the comment was that (taken from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) :

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

And this example illustrates how to use `on` to delegate events instead of `live`.
Also can be seen in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/XgbkQ/5/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not working for me. Here's the html: `<span class="backref_hover match0" original-title=""><span class="backref_hover match1" original-title="Backreference 1: abc">a<span class="backref_hover match2" original-title="Backreference 2: b">b</span>c</span></span>`. I merely changed 'span' to '.backref_hover'

Comment: Still can't get it to work on my end. Does it matter if the elements are created on the fly? I have added "live: true" to the tipsy options, which makes it display popups but they still stack.

Comment: D'oh! Of course it matters! I used your code, merely changed the mousemove event to be live, too. Now it works flawlessly. Thank you so very much!

Comment: no porb. btw, you should probably still use the `on` method (slightly different : `$(mainWrapper).on(event, $tips, handler)` than the deprecated `live` jQuery method.

Comment: I tried using your code, the one with `on` but that did not work. It worked when I changed to `live`. I used your first example with the change i mentioned. How would a proper code sample look like?

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea about this stuff. Well deserved of bounty (in 1 hour)!

Answer (score 1):

If you control the html, how about marking the particular `span` on which you want the tooltip? You could do it with a `class` thus:

```
<span>
    [unknown number of spans]
    <span class="use-tooltip" title="Backreference x: y">def</span>
    [unknown number of close spans]
</span>
```

and your plugin call would be:

```
$('.use-tooltip').tipsy();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your problem, you can solve this by modification the tipsy plugin. You can add your own custom option to parameters (e.g. `hideParentTip: true`) i.e.:

```
$('span span').tipsy({hideParentTip: true});
```

Then you need to modify the plugin itself. On the line `153`,  you need to place next code after the `function enter() {` , that is :

```
function enter() {
    if (options.hideParentTip) $(this).parent().trigger(eventOut);
```

hope that helps. Let me know if it won't

Comment: Modifying the plugin is a bit drastic. If you wish to update the plugin at a later date you'd have to reapply your changes.

Comment: @Spolto  Yes it is, actually that does not solve problem if the inner element is not an immediate descendant either. May be it is better to remove the answer, how do you think?

Comment: See my updated answer for a simple code example that doesn't involve changing the plugin.

Comment: There can be an infinite amount of nested tags, so I guess this doesnt work.

Comment: @Lindrian Is the plugin modification suffice you in general? If it is may be I will invent smth. If not then you probably have to use some else plugin, cause `tipsy` does not have any applicable option, as it seems

Comment: @caligula: tipsy is perfect. It does everything I want. I just need to solve this stack problem.

Comment: @Lindrian I'm afraid that there is no option in tipcy to achieve what you want, without it modification

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try something like this..

```
$(function(){   
    $('body').children('span').tipsy( 
    });​
```

See if it works.. I think it will select all the span tags leaving its children .